# Adding a Powerpoint Title slide using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code running from excel which produces a 6 slide powerpoint presentation using copied in charts from an excel document. What code lines would I use to insert a title slide, and define the text on that slide (title + sub title)? Using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, some additional alternative for @Siddharth Rout proposal (which is good as well). I use `.AddTitle` method which could be beneficial in case of formatting of that shape.

```
Sub add_title()

Dim shpCurrShape As Shape

Dim ppPres As Presentation

Set ppPres = ActivePresentation
With ppPres.Slides(1)

If Not .Shapes.HasTitle Then
    Set shpCurrShape = .Shapes.AddTitle
Else
    Set shpCurrShape = .Shapes.Title
End If

    With shpCurrShape
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        '~~> Set text here
        .Text = "BLAH BLAH"
        '~~> Alignment
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 3
       '~~> Working with font
       With .Font
          .Bold = msoTrue
          .Name = "Tahoma"
          .Size = 24
          .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
       End With
    End With
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for the alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `.AddTextbox` to add the Title

See this example

```
Dim shpCurrShape As Object

'~~> If doing from within PP remove oPPApp else it is your PP object
With oPPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    '~~> Add Heading
    'expression.AddTextbox(Orientation, Left, Top, Width, Height)
    Set shpCurrShape = .Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 18, 48, 654, 29.08126)

    With shpCurrShape
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            '~~> Set text here
            .Text = "BLAH BLAH"
            '~~> Alignment
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 3
           '~~> Working with font
           With .Font
              .Bold = msoTrue
              .Name = "Tahoma"
              .Size = 24
              .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           End With
        End With
    End With
End With
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: One suggestion, as the intention is to add title you could use  `.Shapes.AddTitle` instead of `.Shapes.AddTextbox` which could be beneficial in some situation...

Comment: True. You can use `.AddTitle` as well to restore a previously deleted title placeholder in the slide.:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution which uses the "Add" method, and uses Powerpoint's slideLayout for a Title slide.

```
Sub AddTitleSlide()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim ttlBox As Shape

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
Set ttlBox = sld.Shapes("Title 1")

ttlBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Here is the slide title!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution I use:

```
'Setup PPTX File
Set oPA = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPA.Visible = True
Set oPP = oPA.ActivePresentation
slideNumber = oPP.Slides.Count + 1
Set oPS = oPP.Slides.Add(slideNumber, ppLayoutBlank)
oPA.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (slideNumber) 'this line makes testing easier otherwise not required
Set sObj = oPP.Slides(slideNumber)
sObj.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = titleText

 'Include Text in Powerpoint
oPP.Slides(slideNumber).CustomLayout = oPP.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(X) 'X=Layout Number with a title page
sObj.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = titleText
```