# Using VBA to paste Excel data into Powerpoint, Font Size not changing

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

new to stack overflow posting, so do guide me along. :)

I am required to create a program to paste certain values from excel to powerpoint and format it.

The VBA code I have written so far is able to produce the Cell Value from Excel to PowerPoint. However, the Font Size does not change in Powerpoint while the Font Colour and Font Type will change. I am unsure why this is so but I have a thought that it could be due to some powerpoint settings or something regarding VBA I am not familiar with.

Please Assist!

Codes are below:

```
Dim title1 As Excel.range
Dim App As PowerPoint.Application
Dim Ptn As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape

Set title1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").range("C1:C1")

'Set Font Properties
title1.Font.Size = 28
title1.Font.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
title1.Font.Name = "Century Gothic"


'Create Slide 1
Set mySlide = Ptn.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

'Copy Title1
title1.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault

Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position
myShape.Left = 35
myShape.Top = 200
```

Comment: Try replacing: 
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault 
with 
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject

Comment: It cuts the text off halfway through when I did that. Any way to resize the object so that the whole line of text is displayed instead?

Comment: As in the text size causes it to extend beyond the page, or its only copying half the characters?

Comment: When it is pasted as an OLEObject what is shown is only the first 3 letters of the text, as an image(?) or some sort of object. If I try to lengthen it by dragging the right border horizontally, it only expands the cut off text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically paste your excel field as the title of that slide try:

```
mySlide.Shapes.AddTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title1
```

Edit: you can check if your slide already has a title you can use

```
If Not mySlide.Shapes.HasTitle Then
    mySlide.Shapes.AddTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title1
Else
   mySlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title1
End If
```

AddTitle also has various properties for setting font, format, size, color etc.
See: [Adding a Powerpoint Title slide using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709996/adding-a-powerpoint-title-slide-using-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is you need to add `Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` to paste special. Can you try this?

```
'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, DataType:=ppPasteDefault
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that i replace this line 
  `mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault`  
with this line? 
`mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, DataType:=ppPasteDefault `

Comment: Yes, note that only change is addition of `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`

Comment: Error, named argument not found. I think it's because I'm trying to copy it over to PPT which renders it unworkable.